# How to fire onClick event if RadioButton is checked on page load

Tags: html, onclick, radio-button, pageload

I have a radiobuttongroup where one button is checked upon pageload, is it possible to get some kind of onClick event to fire from that radiobutton upon pageload if it's checked?

I dont whant to use some kind onLoad JavaScript to check it.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why would you not use an onload event when you want the action to happen on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.radioButton:checked').live('click', function(){
// do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need, you could try something like this (jQuery):

```
if($('.radioButton').is(':checked')) { $('.whatever_must_be_clicked).click(); }
```

for the first selector, you can also use the :radio selector $(':radio') or $('input:radio')